# storing an array and displaying it to the screen

Tags: java

I seem to be having a problem with displaying the seat numbers to the screen 
When I compile  its showing me that  every number thats stored in the string is the problem

```
class AirlineSystem{

static int name;

public static void main(String[]args)
            {
String[][] seats = new String[30][6] = {"1a","2a","3a","4a","5a","6a","7a","8a","9a","10a"},
                                        {"11b","12b","13b","14b","15b","16b","17b","18b","19b","20b"},
                                        {"21c","22c","23b","24b","25b","26b","27b","28b","29b","30b"},
                                        {"31d","32d","33d","34d","35d","36d","37d","38d","39d","40d"},
                                        {"41e","42e","43e","44e","45e","46e","47e","48e","49e","50e"},
                                        {"51f","52f","53f","54f","55f","56f","57f","58f","59f","60f"},
                                        {"61g","62g","63g","64g","65g","66g","67g","68g","69g","70g"},
                                        {"71h","72h","73h","74h","75h","76h","77h","78h","79h","80h"},
                                        {"81i","82i","83i","84i","85i","86i","87i","88i","89i","90i"},
                                        {"91j","92j","93j","94j","95j","96j","97j","98j","99j","100j"},
                                        {"101k","102k","103k","104k","105k","106k","107k","108k","109k","110k"},
                                        {"111l","112l","113l","114l","115l","116l","117l","118l","119l","120l"},
                                        {"120m","122m","123m","124m","125m","126m","127m","128m","129m","130m"},
                                        {"131n","132n","133n","134n","135n","136n","137n","138n","139n","140n"},
                                        {"141o","142o","143o","144o","145o","146o","147o","148o","149o","150o"},
                                        {"151p","152p","153p","154p","155p","156p","157p","158p","159p","160p"},
                                        {"161q","162q","163q","164q","165q","166q","167q","168q","169q","170q"},
                                        {"171r","172r","173r","174r","175r","176r","177r","178r","179r","180r"},
                                }

for(i=0;i=seats.length;i++){
System.out.print("Planes seating arrangements"+[seats]);
}

printarray(seats);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally feel the following approach to be a better one:

```
public class AirlineSystem
{
  public AirlineSystem()
  {
    final String[][] seats = initializeSeats(18, 10);
    displaySeatingArrangement(seats);
  }

  private String[][] initializeSeats(final int ROWS, final int COLUMNS)
  {
    final String[][] seats = new String[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    int seatIndex = 1;

    for (int i = 0, ch = 'a'; i < ROWS; i++, ch++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
      {
        seats[i][j] = (seatIndex++) + "" + (char) ch;
      }
    }

    return seats;
  }

  private void displaySeatingArrangement(final String[][] seats)
  {
    System.out.println("Plane Seating Arrangement: ");

    for (String[] row : seats)
    {
      for (String seat : row)
      {
        System.out.printf(" %4s ", seat);
      }

      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new AirlineSystem();
  }
}
```

Its good, as it doesn't require hardcoding of seating arrangement. The for loops generate the arrangement in a much compact manner, and the output is formatted properly for clarity as well.

Comment: Thanks that works well just wondering what final alters when you put it on a integer value

Comment: Well, final keyword is just to declare that, that particular value won't change later in the scope of the particular variable. Like, if I say: `final int a = 10;` then I can't do `a = 11;` later in that scope of code. It just helps the reader of the code know that the programmer hasn't changed the values of the final declared variables in the later part of the code. It makes them constants. You can ignore them in the code, but I like to keep them just to make sure that bugs don't creep into my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access the array in a wrong way, in java when you are trying to access array elements you need to do this

```
array[index]
```

so you will need to change your for loop to:

```
for(i=0;i=seats.length;i++){
    System.out.print("Planes seating arrangements"+seats[i]);
}
```

but since its a 2d array you will need to have nested loops to go through your columns/rows

Hope that helps, but do look up these things before posting on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

not like that you are using  String[][] seats.

so use nested for loop for the retreival

example :

> for() {
>
> for(){ } }

and also seat[i][j];

Answer (score 0):

Your code had many errors. Try it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] seats = new String[][] {
            { "1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "6a", "7a", "8a", "9a", "10a" },
            { "11b", "12b", "13b", "14b", "15b", "16b", "17b", "18b", "19b", "20b" },
            { "21c", "22c", "23b", "24b", "25b", "26b", "27b", "28b", "29b", "30b" },
            { "31d", "32d", "33d", "34d", "35d", "36d", "37d", "38d", "39d", "40d" },
            { "41e", "42e", "43e", "44e", "45e", "46e", "47e", "48e", "49e", "50e" },
            { "51f", "52f", "53f", "54f", "55f", "56f", "57f", "58f", "59f", "60f" },
            { "61g", "62g", "63g", "64g", "65g", "66g", "67g", "68g", "69g", "70g" },
            { "71h", "72h", "73h", "74h", "75h", "76h", "77h", "78h", "79h", "80h" },
            { "81i", "82i", "83i", "84i", "85i", "86i", "87i", "88i", "89i", "90i" },
            { "91j", "92j", "93j", "94j", "95j", "96j", "97j", "98j", "99j", "100j" },
            { "101k", "102k", "103k", "104k", "105k", "106k", "107k", "108k", "109k", "110k" },
            { "111l", "112l", "113l", "114l", "115l", "116l", "117l", "118l", "119l", "120l" },
            { "120m", "122m", "123m", "124m", "125m", "126m", "127m", "128m", "129m", "130m" },
            { "131n", "132n", "133n", "134n", "135n", "136n", "137n", "138n", "139n", "140n" },
            { "141o", "142o", "143o", "144o", "145o", "146o", "147o", "148o", "149o", "150o" },
            { "151p", "152p", "153p", "154p", "155p", "156p", "157p", "158p", "159p", "160p" },
            { "161q", "162q", "163q", "164q", "165q", "166q", "167q", "168q", "169q", "170q" },
            { "171r", "172r", "173r", "174r", "175r", "176r", "177r", "178r", "179r", "180r" } };

    for (int i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Planes seating arrangements " + Arrays.toString(seats[i]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String[][] seats = {{"1a","2a","3a","4a","5a","6a","7a","8a","9a","10a"},
                                        {"11b","12b","13b","14b","15b","16b","17b","18b","19b","20b"},
                                        {"21c","22c","23b","24b","25b","26b","27b","28b","29b","30b"},
                                        {"31d","32d","33d","34d","35d","36d","37d","38d","39d","40d"},
                                        {"41e","42e","43e","44e","45e","46e","47e","48e","49e","50e"},
                                        {"51f","52f","53f","54f","55f","56f","57f","58f","59f","60f"},
                                        {"61g","62g","63g","64g","65g","66g","67g","68g","69g","70g"},
                                        {"71h","72h","73h","74h","75h","76h","77h","78h","79h","80h"},
                                        {"81i","82i","83i","84i","85i","86i","87i","88i","89i","90i"},
                                        {"91j","92j","93j","94j","95j","96j","97j","98j","99j","100j"},
                                        {"101k","102k","103k","104k","105k","106k","107k","108k","109k","110k"},
                                        {"111l","112l","113l","114l","115l","116l","117l","118l","119l","120l"},
                                        {"120m","122m","123m","124m","125m","126m","127m","128m","129m","130m"},
                                        {"131n","132n","133n","134n","135n","136n","137n","138n","139n","140n"},
                                        {"141o","142o","143o","144o","145o","146o","147o","148o","149o","150o"},
                                        {"151p","152p","153p","154p","155p","156p","157p","158p","159p","160p"},
                                        {"161q","162q","163q","164q","165q","166q","167q","168q","169q","170q"},
                                        {"171r","172r","173r","174r","175r","176r","177r","178r","179r","180r"}
                                };

for(String[] d1: seats) {
    for (String d2 : d1) {
        System.out.printf("%s\t",d2);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: @user3484893, der wer few errors in array definition